# Is it possible to start my activity from Android calendar reminder notification?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications

My app will create some events and reminders in Android calendar, which will show notifications in Android notification drawer when events coming. Now my question is how (possibly) can I start my own activity from Android calendar reminder notifications? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can only start an activity (or perform any action) without the user interference, if you're listening to [Broadcast Receivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and the event that you wish to interact with sends a broadcast.

If the Android Calendar sends broadcasts (which I doubt), then yes, otherwise there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest add:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".receiver.NotificationReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EVENT_REMINDER" />
            <data android:scheme="content"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Create a NotificationReceiver like this:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public NotificationReceiver() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(CalendarContract.ACTION_EVENT_REMINDER)) {
         // Do whatever you want here
    }
}
}
```

Replace the comment with the code to start the activity.

Comment: if I kill my app from the recent app try then I am unable to receive this broadcast.

Comment: @RehanSarwar well.... that makes sense, right? If you kill the Broadcast Receiver ...... how are you going to..... you know...... receive.... the .... broadcasts?

Comment: So is there any way to get the WakeUp or any Broadcast even my app is killed I want to perform some other tasks when the event will be fired?